# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 won't start: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, ssms

I'm on Windows 7 Professional SP1.

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014 using the 64-bit download from Microsoft: SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe, and when I click on the shortcut in the Programs menu, it gives the error:

*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*

I checked the shortcut properties, and the Target path is correctly set to:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

However, it was missing the "Start in" value, so I set it to that folder, but the error still occurs.  When I navigate directly to the binary Ssms.exe and double-click on it, the application does run.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the shortcut to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the **Number One Rule of Windows**: When in doubt, reboot.

That fixed whatever the problem was.

Answer (score -1):

The problem are also caused by the .NET Framework 4.0 series.
Uninstall it in Program and features and install .NET Framework 6 and newer
Problem solved